In a higher-order effect in polysemy for abstract while language interpreter
I have this problem, where I want to build an interpreter for an abstract form of the while language. In the condition of the while, I have an m Bool which needs to be evaluated before every loop execution. However, I have not yet found a way to extract/use the boolean out of the monad. I have made a while program for a factorial function to clarify how I want to use the while. Can anybody help me figure out how to solve this?
import Polysemy
import Polysemy.State
import Prelude hiding (lookup, log)
import Data.Map
import Data.Maybe

type WhileLangState = Map String Double

data WhileLang m a where
    Assign :: String -> Double -> WhileLang m ()
    While :: m Bool -> m () -> WhileLang m ()
    GetVar :: String -> WhileLang m Double

makeSem ''WhileLang

runWhileLang :: Member (State WhileLangState) r => Sem (WhileLang : r) a -> Sem r a
runWhileLang = interpretH $ \case
    (Assign s d) -> do
      state <- get
      put (insert s d state)
      pureT ()
    (While cond body) -> do
        body' <- runT body
        cond' <- runT cond
        let loop = do
              if cond' -- how can I get the boolean?
                then body' >> loop
                else pure ()
        _ <- pureT loop
        pureT ()
    (GetVar s) -> do
      state <- get
      pureT $ fromMaybe 0 (lookup s state)

whileFactorial :: Member WhileLang r => Sem r ()
whileFactorial = do
  assign "n" 8
  assign "result" 1

  while ((> 0) <$> getVar "n") $ do
    result <- getVar "result"
    currentN <- getVar "n"
    assign "result" (result * currentN)
    assign "n" (currentN - 1)


Not sure I understand what the problem is. You get the boolean "out" of cond' the usual way, using >>= or b <- cond', or you can use something like whileM_ cond' body instead of reinventing the wheel.

I'm not a polysemy expert. Could you include the type of runT? If it's typeclass polymorphic, which instance(s) are used (or are you hoping to be used) in the given snippet?

I'm not familiar with how polysemy works but based on the types of the API, it looks like you can use getInspectorT to get a function f x -> Maybe x that lets you inspect values produced by computations, getInitialState to get an "initial state", and bindTSimple to thread the state through the handled computation. I don't know in what situations the function returned by getInspectorT produces Nothing.
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TemplateHaskell, LambdaCase, GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Polysemy
import Polysemy.State
import Prelude hiding (lookup, log)
import Data.Map
import Data.Maybe

type WhileLangState = Map String Double

data WhileLang m a where
    Assign :: String -> Double -> WhileLang m ()
    While :: m Bool -> m () -> WhileLang m ()
    GetVar :: String -> WhileLang m Double

makeSem ''WhileLang

runWhileLang :: Member (State WhileLangState) r => Sem (WhileLang : r) a -> Sem r a
runWhileLang = interpretH $ \case
    (Assign s d) -> do
      state <- get
      put (insert s d state)
      pureT ()
    (While cond body) -> do
      inspector <- getInspectorT
      let loop unit = do
            cond' <- bindTSimple (\() -> cond) unit
            if fromJust (inspect inspector cond') then
              bindTSimple (\() -> body) unit >>=
              loop
            else
              pure unit
      unit <- getInitialStateT
      loop unit
    (GetVar s) -> do
      state <- get
      pureT $ fromMaybe 0 (lookup s state)

whileFactorial :: Member WhileLang r => Sem r ()
whileFactorial = do
  assign "n" 8
  assign "result" 1

  while ((> 0) <$> getVar "n") $ do
    result <- getVar "result"
    currentN <- getVar "n"
    assign "result" (result * currentN)
    assign "n" (currentN - 1)

-- Run the example
main :: IO ()
main = runM (runState (empty :: WhileLangState) (runWhileLang whileFactorial)) >>= print


Thank you very much, that works. You just saved me from a lot of troubleshooting.
